# Can you claim a training course in Canada if you are provided a receipt but not a T2202A form?

Tags: canada, tax-credit, tuition

I completed a 200h Yoga Teacher Training course in Canada but noticed that most yoga schools are not HRSDC certified providers, so am wondering if tuition tax credits can still be claimed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the provider of your course is not certified as a "designated educational institution", then your tuition costs cannot be claimed. Usually, if you weren't issued a T2202A form by the course provider, then they probably haven't been certified by the Minister of Employment and Social Development Canada. But it doesn't hurt to call them and check. You can also call the CRA at 1-800-959-8281 to obtain a list of designated educational institutions.

See [Eligible Tuition Fees](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/ddctns/lns300-350/323/lgbl-eng.html) and [Designated Educational Institution](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/tchncl/ncmtx/fls/s1/f2/s1-f2-c1-eng.html#p1.9) for full details.